# Best practices for handling uncaught Node exceptions with Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am writing a website with express and I found out that an uncaught exception would bring down the whole server(at least in debug mode).

Of course I could wrap every handler with `(...).catch(err)` and pass error with `next(err)`, but that is just bad practice and wouldn't solve the problem (that the server goes down on uncaught error).

Before express I only had experience with Laravel and Laravel handles uncaught errors gracefully by sending a 500 to the user, unlike express.

Any thoughts? Perhaps this is easily googleable and I am being dumb asking this, but so far the best approach I found is catch every error manually (which is bad practice IMO, as it leaves possibility of server going down on uncaught exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to promises, you can write a single wrapper function that catches every error and calls `next(err)` for you, or use this package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler

Otherwise, you should catch every asynchronous error.

Express is *old* and was written in a time before promises. There's some nicer frameworks out there these days that have better default behavior.

Comment: Thank you, this is useful. What are some good js frameworks that support promise exceptions?

Comment: I found a good replacement for express.js: https://www.fastify.io/ . It is not only ~1.5x faster, but also handles promises like it should

Answer (score 0):

Express already catches synchronous exceptions for you and already calls `next(err)`.  All you need is an [Express error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) defined.

Here's the simplest example:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
});
```

Express will not catch asynchronous exceptions or promise rejections for you automatically.  To catch promise-rejections, you will have to do some sort of wrapper for all route handlers.  There are a variety of ways to implement this wrapper.  I've written a bit of a patch for Express that I sometimes use in my apps that automatically handles promise rejections in route handlers if they return a promise or if they are `async` and an `await` sees a rejected promise.  It's unfortunate that Express is not being updated to handle this type of thing.

Asynchronous (callback-based) errors must be handled inside the callback since there's no universal way to propagate that error anywhere (this is why promise rejections are a better way to code).